# 0 supported devices when using sip feature

Tags: android, sip, uses-feature

My application uses android native sip library, and I add this line to assure the app can be found only by devices support it:
`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" android:required="true" />`

On market publish page it said my app has these features:

```
android.hardware.MICROPHONE
android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT
android.hardware.sip.VOIP
android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN
android.hardware.WIFI
```

But the number of supported devices is 0.
If I remove sip feature, the number of supported devices is 3823.
Why did it happen? I am sure that at least my HTC new One can run it properly.

*update*
I found that even the official SipDemo sample project supports 0 devices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#sw-features), you should be using `android.software.sip.voip`, not `android.hardware.sip.voip`. I think your app is showing up with 0 supported devices because Google Play does not know about `android.hardware.sip.voip`. Also, you should set `android:required="false"` unless your app cannot function at all without SIP/VOIP support.

Comment: Thank you, it does work! Don't why they have hardware.sip in official sample project...

Comment: @Leonhart - No idea about the sample project. File a bug report. :)